# Parse.com check if user boolean is true Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to make a login app for my parse webapp to check if a column of a boolean is true then to appear the proper HTML content
but if the boolean is false, it should appear just the error alert.
So my login form is this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Testin</title>
<script>
 Parse.initialize("APPID", "JSKEY");
 angular.module('AuthApp', [])
.run(['$rootScope', function($scope) {
  $scope.scenario = 'Log in';
  $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current();
  $scope.logIn = function(form) {
    Parse.User.logIn(form.username, form.password, {
      success: function(user) {
        $scope.currentUser = user;
        $scope.$apply();
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        alert("Unable to log in: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
  };  
  $scope.logOut = function(form) {
    Parse.User.logOut();
    $scope.currentUser = null;
  };
}]);
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="AuthApp">
 <div ng-hide="currentUser">
    <form ng-show="scenario == 'Sign up'">
      <a href="#" ng-click='scenario="Log in"'>Log in</a>
    </form>
    <form ng-show="scenario == 'Log in'">
      <h2>Log in</h2>
      Username: <input type="text" ng-model="user.username" /><br />
      Password: <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" /><br />
      <button ng-click="logIn(user)">Log in</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="currentUser">
    <p> You Are logged in as a chef</p>
      <input type="button" id="submitId" value="submit">
       <button ng-click="logOut(user)">Log out</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the Class _Users i have a column which is called "chef"
This column is boolean and it's true or false.
[image]
My question is, when i check in the Log In, the username and the password, is there any way to check if the boolean in this column is true or false?
And if its true to get in the success function, if its false to go to the error function !

I think its the same as the check for verified email, because that column it's a boolean too.

Comment: not sure if i got your question correctly. where do you want to do this check? On server while checking for login or on UI? If you want to enter error function then an error status code has be be returned from server.

Comment: @S4beR i want the check to be done at the same time that it checks for the username and password if they are correct. Its something like this, `if (username == true && password == true && chef == true)`

Comment: if you have access to DB table then you should have that extra column (chef) also. what is preventing you from reading the value of `chef` and applying your condition?

Comment: @S4beR I can have access after `success: function(user) {`  could you tell me an example of how to set the condition ?

Comment: well I would always prefer to do this check on server (for security reason) but if you want to do this on your client side code you can modify your success function to do something like `if (user.chef) { // existing code to set user} else {// show error}`

Comment: you would actually nee to use `if (user.get('chef')) {...}`